# Forum date Response based on if statement matches 1 of 12 equal to or greater than comparisons (arguements)

Tags: php, datetime, if-statement, switch-statement

Ok So I am working on a forum submit php code, lets call the file name ***index.html*** that takes forum date submitted in first below code.

```
<center>
  <form name="birthDay" method="post" action="months.php">
    <input type="date" id="birthDay" name="birthDay"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="send"><br>
  </form>
</center>
```

The php file ***months.php*** will take variable birthday and submit it to the months php file. as such.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['birthDay'])) {
  $link = $_POST['birthDay']; //Month for Jan 
  $janBegin = date("01-01"); 
  $janEnd = date("01-31");  

  if ($birthDate >= $janBegin || $birthDate <= $janEnd) { 
    echo "Your birthday month is janurary"; 
  } 
?>
```

And so on based on all 12 months . When submitting forum.

My question is how do I create the list for the variable "birthday" to be compared to all months start and end date?

I have looked at if, elseif, swith-case statements but nothing is not creating desired results? I may be doing something wrong. But not able to pinpoint the error in my code.

That's what brings me here.

Any help on this is very much appreciated. Thanks

**As Per Requested Via ADyson**

This code is just an example of what I am trying to do. I have stated in comments below that start and end dates will be set at random variables. Total Variables set will be 12. This is why I choose to use beginning and end dates of the month. ADyson I believe took the idea a bit more literal Then I was hoping.

Basically Code will look like this.

```
<?php 
$startdate1 = date("01/20") 
$enddate1=date("02/27") 
if ($bday >= $startdate1 && $bday <= $enddate1) {
  echo "response #1";
```

I also have been researching more into this and found a snippet of code using if and elseif statements witch I found to work. But still come across an issue.

When date is entered and it loops through the code It matches a wrong response. so say a date of `08/27 (m-d)` is entered it stops and matches

```
$option11Begin = date("11/25"); 
$option11End = date("12/23");
```

comparison

```
} elseif ($bday >= $option11Begin && $bday <= $option11End) {
```

any idea's why this is happening. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to compare to start and end dates or have massive switch statements. Just feed the date into PHP's built-in `DateTime` class, which specialises in processing dates, and then output only the month name from the resulting object.

```
if(isset($_POST['birthDay'])) {
  $bday = new DateTime($_POST['birthDay']);
  echo "Your birthday month is ".$bday->format("F");
}
```

Simulation: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f4b8730927927adf976dfb103c58ba132ca9217f

Documentation link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

This solution will work for any day of the month. It parses the date string, and then from the resulting `DateTime` object you can always get the month value - or any other information you want, or do other comparisons to other `DateTime` objects, or whatever you need. This is much easier and more reliable than any kind of string comparisons

Comment: First Ty for responding. & this is a great answer but it really does not give the insight I am searching for. I based my question and the code of a project that I am not willing to really share online. This example of code is as close as I could come to the real project. But I will need a comparison of two dates of a list of 12 items to compare the entered date. As shown in the example I have a equal to or greater/less than a date in the comparison of each of the 12 items. To produce the desired results. Any ideas what I might want to consider to make this work. Thanks.

Comment: `But I will need a comparison of two dates of a list of 12 items to compare the entered date`...why will you need that? My code gives you the exact same outcome in a much simpler way. Did you run the demo I provided, and see that it works? I can't imagine why you would prefer a more complicated solution. Are there some additional requirements which you haven't mentioned, perhaps?

Comment: Q:Why will I need to do this? A:Because the dates compared are not actually going to be the first and last of the month. So to restate - You are right the code you gave does work for this and i did test it. But like I mentioned before this is an alteration of the project code I am working on so the bases of comparing date entered to set start and end date to reproduce desired response. The actual date change to set dates may nave been a additional requirement I was not sure to mention. Hence giving away the core secrecy of the project. I just need to compare for 12 possibilities for an answer

Comment: `the dates compared are not actually going to be the first and last of the month.`...that doesn't matter, my solution will work for any day of the month - try it. It parses the date string, and then from the resulting DateTime object you can always get the month value - or any other information you want, or do other comparisons to other DateTime objects, or whatever you need. This is much easier and more reliable than any kind of string comparisons.

Comment: As I said before I have to use two separate dates. These dates will be different for each of the 12 responses I will be retrieving by results of entered date. your code only works for setting the time date match to systems date and time?. Can you give an example of the code with two different set dates? I apologizes if my question was not clear enough to explain what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: `These dates will be different for each of the 12 responses I will be retrieving by results of entered date`...different in what way exactly? And how will you determine the dates to use in each case? In your question, you simply said the 12 dates would be `all months start and end date`. Are you now saying the start and dates you need to compare the input against might not always be the start and end of a month? If the requirements have changed, you need to update the question, and include examples.

Comment: `your code only works for setting the time date match to systems date and time`...no that's not true, it will work for any date you input into it. The live demo I provided (https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f4b8730927927adf976dfb103c58ba132ca9217f) already shows it working with a specific date provided as input, not the system date. Here's an example of it working with a different input date: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9cc900c28ab6fcb8cab84187996ddcefbfb0555f . Execute the examples on those pages to see the results.

Comment: Done. If you need more let me know.

Comment: Can you also remove the now-incorrect bit about always using the start and end dates of months...why did you say that to begin with, if it was never the case? If you give a specific requirement, people will give you the most efficient implementation of that requirement. If the requirement is actually broader, then you need to always make that clear. Make the question make sense with what you actually want now. There's no need to keep bits of it which aren't relevant any more.